# writeLines is not returning text

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, data-science

I want to display the entire (or partial) textual content of 400+ documents I have in a Corpus. To do so I've used the function `writeLines` but it doesn't return the actual text contained in the document, instead it returns this:

> list(list(content = c("", ""), meta = list(author = character(0),   atetimestamp = list(sec = 33.0082728862762, min = 22, hour = 12, mday = 5, mon   = 8, year = 116, wday = 1, yday = 248, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading......

This is how I've coded:

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

#Partition each cell in Excel into separate document
textdata <- read.csv("C:/Users/biat/Documents/survey/openanswers.csv", header = FALSE)
require(tm)

doc <- Corpus(DataframeSource(textdata), readerControl = list(language="swedish"))

writeLines(as.character(doc))
```

Does the problem lie in the R-code or in the CSV file? When I've used `writeLines` together with `DirSource` it returns the text. Anyone know how to suppress the info it returns above and how to retrieve only the text in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following to have the text printed to your console, this is what you ask for if I understand well?

```
library(tm)
data("crude") # example set from tm
output <- sapply( crude, function(x) x$content) #get the content from your object
cat(output) # have your text outputted
```

ps: try and supply a reproducible example for your questions